# Segmentation fault (2D array with dynamic memory allocation) in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, dynamic, allocation

I am still getting a hang of using malloc, calloc or realloc. Pretty sure I'm getting a segmentation fault because of an incorrect pointer or something, but for the life of me, I don't understand where I'm doing it wrong. The program works when the user input is '5 5', anything other than that causes the program to act weird and often times fail with a segmentation fault. Matrix A and B should be filled with random numbers, and Matrix C should sum matrix A and B, all the while using dynamic memory allocation. I'm not familiar with allocs, I've just started to understand pointers and 2D arrays. Can somebody explain what I'm doing wrong. Here's the whole code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define ROWS 10
#define COLUMNS 10

void fillMatrix (int *matrix, int rows, int columns)
{
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for(j= 0; j < columns; j++)
        {
            matrix[i * COLUMNS + j] = (rand() % 10) + 1;
        }
    }
}
void printMatrix (int *matrix, int rows, int columns)
{
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for(j= 0; j < columns; j++)
        {
            printf("%2d ", *(matrix + i * COLUMNS + j));
        }
    printf("\n\n");
    }
}
void sumMatrix (int *matrix, int *matrixA, int *matrixB, int rows, int columns)
{
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for(j= 0; j < columns; j++)
        {
            matrix[i * COLUMNS + j] = matrixA[i * COLUMNS + j] + matrixB[i * COLUMNS + j];
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int *matrixA = NULL, *matrixB = NULL, *matrixC = NULL;
    int matrix[ROWS][COLUMNS], r, s, i;
    srand((unsigned) time(NULL));
    do{
    printf("Rows and columns (min 1 1, max 10 10): ");
    scanf("%d %d", &r, &s);
    }while(r > ROWS || r < 1 || s > COLUMNS || s < 1);

    matrixA = malloc(r * sizeof(int *));
    for (i = 0; i < r; i++)
        matrixA[i] = malloc(s * sizeof(int));

    printf("\nMatrix A:\n\n");
    fillMatrix(matrixA, r, s);
    printMatrix(matrixA, r, s);

    matrixB = calloc(r, sizeof(int *));
    for (i = 0; i < r; i++)
        matrixB[i] = calloc(s, sizeof(int));

    printf("\nMatrix B:\n\n");
    fillMatrix(matrixB, r, s);
    printMatrix(matrixB, r, s);

    matrixC = calloc(r, sizeof(int *));
    for (i = 0; i < r; i++)
        matrixC[i] = calloc(s, sizeof(int));

    printf("\nSummed up (Matrix C):\n\n");
    sumMatrix(matrixC, matrixA, matrixB, r, s);
    printMatrix(matrixC, r, s);

    free(matrixA);
    free(matrixB);
    free(matrixC);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think matrixA, B and C be of type `int**` (`int **matrixA = NULL, **matrixB = NULL, **matrixC = NULL;`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You access all your matrices as single-dimension arrays, and should therefore allocate them accordingly.

For example: `int* matrixA = malloc(r*s*sizeof(int));`.

That's all; no need to do the `for (i = 0; i < r; i++)` loops.

In addition, you are using the `COLUMNS` macro instead of the `columns` argument in all your functions.

Obviously, if `COLUMNS > columns`, then you'll end up with a memory access violation at some point...

Comment: Still getting the same error. Can you test the code on your machine and make the input '3 3' for example? It crashes... Albeit, I've tried this already, the above written code is the result of my fiddling around with malloc and calloc. The problem still persists. P.S. Changing my code to this actually makes it crash on '5 5' as well now.

Comment: @VengeanceIsMine: Did you get rid of the `for (i = 0; i < r; i++)` loops?

Comment: Yes, for example: int* matrixA = malloc(r * s * sizeof(int));

    printf("\nMatrix A:\n\n");
    fillMatrix(matrixA, r, s);
    printMatrix(matrixA, r, s);

Comment: @VengeanceIsMine: You are using the preprocessor definition COLUMNS instead of the argument columns in all your functions!!! You need to change that (added to the answer above).

Comment: Okay, tried it, still not working for me. Must've misunderstood you, but the problem persisted. Used the code by BLUEPIXY, now it works. Thank you anyways!

Comment: @VengeanceIsMine: No problem, but please note that BLUEPIXY's code is also using the `COLUMNS` macro instead of the `columns` argument. And that, to my humble opinion, will ultimately lead to an error.

Comment: I see! I took your advice though, and changed it to what it should be (the columns argument instead COLUMNS). So I think you deserve to be named the accepted answer. After all, you did take your time to explain it to me. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the memory locations in your matrix are not contiguous. But in all your print/fill/sum matrix functions, you are assuming that they are.

Assume a 2x2 matrix A. Your code will allocate memory in the following way.
addr1 is starting address of one array, addr2 is of the second.

A[0] addr1         (addr1+sizeof(int))
A[1] addr2         (addr2+sizeof(int))

But this is what you need:

A[0] addr1                    addr1 + sizeof(int)
A[1] (addr1 + 2*sizeof(int))    (addr1 + 3*sizeof(int))

So you need to replace your malloc statements into one single malloc:
matrixA = malloc(r*s*sizeof(int))
Also, you are assuming that each row has COLUMN number of elements and not 's' number. If that's the case, you should malloc:
matrixA = malloc(r*COLUMNS*sizeof(int)), but I am not sure why you need the other unused columns.

Also, int matrix[ROWS][COLUMNS] seems to be unused.

Comment: Oh, I understand now. Thank you for painting a picture for me! And that argument at the end is totally valid, I forgot about deleting that line. Again, thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

have problem with malloc, you're trying to create array of arrays instead of 2d array, you should fix it so:

```
matrixA = malloc(r * c * sizeof(int)); // no any kind of additional for loop here, 1 malloc per matrix
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define ROWS 10
#define COLUMNS 10

void fillMatrix (int *matrix, int rows, int columns)
{
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for(j= 0; j < columns; j++)
        {
            matrix[i * COLUMNS + j] = (rand() % 10) + 1;
        }
    }
}
void printMatrix (int *matrix, int rows, int columns)
{
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for(j= 0; j < columns; j++)
        {
            printf("%2d ", matrix[ i * COLUMNS + j]);
        }
        printf("\n\n");
    }
}
void sumMatrix (int *matrix, int *matrixA, int *matrixB, int rows, int columns)
{
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for(j= 0; j < columns; j++)
        {
            matrix[i * COLUMNS + j] = matrixA[i * COLUMNS + j] + matrixB[i * COLUMNS + j];
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int *matrixA = NULL, *matrixB = NULL, *matrixC = NULL;
    int matrix[ROWS][COLUMNS], r, s, i;
    srand((unsigned) time(NULL));
    do{
    printf("Rows and columns (min 1 1, max 10 10): ");
    scanf("%d %d", &r, &s);
    }while(r > ROWS || r < 1 || s > COLUMNS || s < 1);

    matrixA = malloc(COLUMNS*r * sizeof(int));

    printf("\nMatrix A:\n\n");
    fillMatrix(matrixA, r, s);
    printMatrix(matrixA, r, s);

    matrixB = calloc(r*COLUMNS,sizeof(int));

    printf("\nMatrix B:\n\n");
    fillMatrix(matrixB, r, s);
    printMatrix(matrixB, r, s);

    matrixC = calloc(r*COLUMNS, sizeof(int));

    printf("\nSummed up (Matrix C):\n\n");
    sumMatrix(matrixC, matrixA, matrixB, r, s);
    printMatrix(matrixC, r, s);

    free(matrixA);
    free(matrixB);
    free(matrixC);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This one works for me. Can you just, in layman's terms, explain to me what and why should've been replaced.

Comment: @VengeanceIsMine You're mixed up in the handling of the array. My answer was unified to be treated as a one-dimensional array.

Comment: @VengeanceIsMine , I think it is a good `COLUMNS` replaced by `s` and `columns` because it is a waste of memory.

Comment: Exactly, I changed it because of this. Thanks for your input.